# How to blur a relativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi my app contain a service class.In service class I have a `WindowManager` which contains a `RelativeLayout` init.I want to blur the relative layout so that everything behind that will look blurred.I have got some blurring code but they work only in Activity class not in service class.So,are there any solution.I want to simply blur a relativeLayout so that everything behind that will look blurrish.

The code that I use to blur the layout

http://pastebin.com/7Yh9pH6J

Comment: `"I have got some blurring code but they work only in Activity class not in service class"` whats the difference if you call it in activity or service?

Comment: @pskink if I call that code in main activity class it works perfectly and blur the whole layout and I have created a same relative layout programmatically in service class and when I try to blur that relative layout in service class it gives me null pointer exception and crashes.

Comment: again, there is no difference where you call `Bitmap` bluring code, something wrong is with how you are calling that code in both cases

Comment: @pskink please see my code I have updated my question

Comment: so check why `Bitmap viewScreenshot` is null

Comment: @pskink Yaa I am also researching in it why is it happening:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes send `Context` or `Activity` parameter to services class of Activity and then use like that:

**In Service class:**

```
public void functionname(Context context) {
    //do what u want
}
```

**In Activity class:**

```
//call this function in activity class
functionname(this);
```

Comment: OK that mean I have to use the layout of mainActivity in service class